# Magento Fault Code 1 No other info available

Tags: php, api, magento, soap, e-commerce

I am trying to use the Magento API to UPDATE a product. I am getting error code #1 with the following message:`<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [1] Internal Error. Please see log for details.`

Below is my PHP that calls the service and should update three attributes. The Magento api documentation leaves a lot to the imagination so I am stuck

```
$ItemNmbr = $itemData->Item->ItemNmbr;
$ItemDesc = $itemData->Item->ItemDesc; 
$UnitPrce = $itemData->Item->UnitPrce;

$client = new SoapClient('http://website.com/store/api/?wsdl');

$session = $client->login('apiname', 'apipassword');
$result = $client->call($session, 'catalog_product.update', array(168, array(
    'description' => $ItemDesc,
    'price' => $UnitPrce,
    'weight' => $Weight
)));

var_dump ($result);
```

I am statically setting the ProductID above for now. Any information that will help me understand what I am doing wrong would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have access to the Magento installation - if so turn on exception logging, try again and lets see if anything is logged there. At the moment your question implies an error but no information on what the error could be.